# loop over characters in string, NewLISP

Tags: string, text-processing, newlisp

I need to loop over the characters in a given string--in Ruby, I'd do something like this:

```
string = "blah"

string.each_char do |c| 

   puts c

end
```

How do I do this in newLisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `dostring` supplies integers:

```
(let (str "")
(dostring (c str)
  (println (format "%x" c))))

1f604
1f603
1f600
1f60a
```

whereas `explode` supplies the characters:

```
(let (str "")
(dolist (c (explode str))
  (println c)))
```

Comment: that's why I use `(char)` to cast those integers back into characters, silly.  :P  (It converts them into `ASCII/UTF-8` codes).  Didn't know about `(explode)`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
(let (str "blah")  

   (dostring (c str)

      (println (char c) )))
```